# How to update the values of Multiple Components in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react project name is "counter-app" and it has multiple components,
I want to update the values of every counter button but at that instance there is a problem arise

Code snippet of `Counter.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count : 0
    };

    handleIncrement = product => {
      console.log(product);
      this.setState({ count : this.state.count + 1 }); 
    };

    render() { 
        return (
         <div>
            <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button 
             onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)} 
             className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
            >
                Increment
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
    
    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount(){
        const {count} = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
    }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)